# Can APKs compiled for x86 be uploaded to the Amazon Appstore?

Tags: android, x86, apk, amazon-appstore

Google's Play Store lets you upload multiple APKs for your app, one for ARM processors and one for x86 processors, so Intel based Android devices can run the app natively. Can I do the same in the Amazon Appstore? I've tried uploading a second binary but it says my x86 APK is not supported by ANYTHING, not only Amazon devices, it also says it won't work with any non-Amazon Android device.
Is that true or is that an incorrect analysis? It doesn't let me submit my application anyway, unless I remove my x86 APK so the only available APK is the ARM one. Is there any way around that so I can submit an app with both an ARM APK and an x86 APK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regrettably, no. Amazon Appstore does not support x86 architecture, so it won't be possible to upload 2 binaries of different architecture. Only ARM is supported at the moment.